# I cannot add php in a header.php file

Tags: php

I have no idea why I cannot add some php codes inside a php header file.

I have these codes, but the php part doesn't work and the error is

```
    Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''
```

Here are the html and php codes:

```
<img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="projects.php">Browse Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="input_form.php">Add Project</a></li>
<li><a href="adduser.php">Add User</a></li>
<li><a href="About.php">About</a></li>

<?
echo "<li><a href="Search.php">Search</a></li>";
?>
<li><a href="mainlogin.php">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: echo "<li><a href='Search.php'>Search</a></li>";

Comment: Why do you use PHP tag?

Comment: So many answers and noone notices that. No need for php tags there at all.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the following

```
<?
    echo "<li><a href="Search.php">Search</a></li>";
?>
```

with:

```
<?php
    echo "<li><a href='Search.php'>Search</a></li>";
?>
```

As I couldn't find any use of PHP tags in the section where you are using it, you can also try

```
<li><a href='Search.php'>Search</a></li>
```

instead of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `<?` with `<?php` and change double quote `"search.php"` into single quote `'search.php'`

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to mark it as an answer if you think it is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You missed single quotes and php tag:

```
<?php
    echo "<li><a href='Search.php'>Search</a></li>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP shorttags are not always supported on some servers.

Use this instead:

```
<?php
    echo "<li><a href='Search.php'>Search</a></li>";
?>
```

More about shorttags and why not to use it: http://kovshenin.com/2012/reminder-dont-use-the-short-php-open-tag/

One question: Why are you using php to link to that page?

Answer (score 0):

I have a habit of using single quote as default unless there are escape sequence inside the string. This way I don't have to remember to escape double quotes (which occurs in a string more often then a single quote). In your case, if you insist to use double quotes in your `<a>` tag, then you may want to change the echo statement from

```
echo "<li><a href="Search.php">Search</a></li>";
```

to

```
echo '<li><a href="Search.php">Search</a></li>';
```

otherwise you would have to escape the double quotes

```
echo "<li><a href=\"Search.php\">Search</a></li>";
```

A decent editor with syntax highlighting should highlight your problem in a more intuitive way ("anything enclosed in double quotes should appear in the same color"). You can already see your code isn't right by looking at your post.

As mentioned by the others, you may want to change your PHP opening tag to `<?php` instead of just `<?` for a lot of reasons. But your current setup seem to work with short tags just fine.